# Add metadata to 16 bit colored png (48 bit) Python

Tags: png

I need to transfer metadata from one png file to another (adobe lightroom settings there). The problem is that these are color files with a color depth of 16 bits per channel. Accordingly, PIL pngInfo does not work with them (it cut to 8bit per channel), and opencv does not support metadata.
Actually, what to do?
Thank you.